# data type / data element for RFC destination

Tags: abap, saprfc

Is there any default created data type / element for destination? I know that I can use string, but string is very wide open. Is there any limit in destinations name?

```
DATA: dest type ???.

CALL FUNCTION 'NAME'
    DESTINATION dest.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common to use the data element `RFCDEST` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just STRING? I usualy use STRING.

Comment: Well there could be a limitation in a RFC Destination and since `string` has no limitation, it's not a good practice and some errors / missunderstandings could occur.